# Understanding how index works

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `prospectos` (
  `provincia` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `telefono_fijo` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `telefono_movil` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`provincia`),
  KEY `nombre_idx` (`nombre`),
  KEY `tel_fijo_idx` (`provincia`,`telefono_fijo`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tel_movil_idx` (`provincia`,`telefono_movil`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35142 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
 PARTITION BY RANGE (`provincia`)
(PARTITION `p01` VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
..
..
..
PARTITION `p24` VALUES LESS THAN (25) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION `p99` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

doing this search is using both fields in primary key

explain format=json select * from prospectos where provincia = 20 and id = 23;

```
query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "prospectos",
      "partitions": ["p20"],
      "access_type": "const",
      "possible_keys": ["PRIMARY", "tel_fijo_idx", "tel_movil_idx"],
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "key_length": "5",
      "used_key_parts": ["id", "provincia"],
      "ref": ["const", "const"],
      "rows": 1,
      "filtered": 100
```

Now doing another select to use a different key why is not using both fields?

explain format=json select * from prospectos where provincia = 20 and telefono_fijo = 3424527000;

```
"query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "prospectos",
      "partitions": ["p20"],
      "access_type": "ref",
      "possible_keys": ["tel_fijo_idx", "tel_movil_idx"],
      "key": "tel_fijo_idx",
      "key_length": "1",
      "used_key_parts": ["provincia"],
      "ref": ["const"],
      "rows": 16042,
      "filtered": 100,
      "attached_condition": "prospectos.telefono_fijo = 3424527000"
```

It use only provincia on tel_fijo_idx and not telefono_fijo for searching.

Why this search is not using both fields???

Answer (score 0):

Because `telefono_fijo` in the query is unquoted its treated by as a number.

Because of [type conversion](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/type-conversion/). "if one argument is string and the other argument is integer, they are compared as decimals" (from MariaDB-10.3.36 (and other releases from last month)). On older versions they would be compared as as a floating point real number.

So with your query, MariaDB needs to convert every `telefono_fijo` to decimal (or float if earlier) and because conversion takes place, this aspect of the index isn't used.

One solution is to quote `telefono_fijo` in the query to be treated as a string. This is good if the phone number can contain leading `0` or other non-numerical characters. Even in this case using utf8 is probably excessive and an ascii/latin/binary character set is sufficient.

```
explain format=json select * from prospectos where provincia = 20 and telefono_fijo = "3424527000"

{
"query_block": {
"select_id": 1,
"table": {
"table_name": "prospectos",
"access_type": "ref",
"possible_keys": ["tel_fijo_idx", "tel_movil_idx"],
"key": "tel_fijo_idx",
"key_length": "48",
"used_key_parts": ["provincia", "telefono_fijo"],
"ref": ["const", "const"],
"rows": 1,
"filtered": 100,
"index_condition": "prospectos.telefono_fijo = '3424527000'"
}
}
}
```

The other solution for the (10.3.36 and other versions released on/after 15 Aug 2022 ([release notes for date](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes/))) is to use the decimal type for `telefono_finjo` on the assumption that numbers without leading 0s occur is the dataset. (`alter table prospectos modify telefono_fijo decimal(15) NOT NULL`). When this is done, the index will be used (note `used_key_parts` in `explain`) regardless if the constant filter for `telefono_fijo` is quoted like a string, or unquoted like a number.

```
explain format=json select * from prospectos where provincia = 20 and telefono_fijo = 3424527000

{
"query_block": {
"select_id": 1,
"table": {
"table_name": "prospectos",
"access_type": "ref",
"possible_keys": ["tel_fijo_idx", "tel_movil_idx"],
"key": "tel_fijo_idx",
"key_length": "8",
"used_key_parts": ["provincia", "telefono_fijo"],
"ref": ["const", "const"],
"rows": 1,
"filtered": 100
}
}
}
```

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gp1RdYq-)

Comment: excelent info, i will keep telephone as varchar, because i think is more flexible than a number type a use quotes for the select, I am new in php+mysql, and I dont pay attention to this kind of details.

Comment: When conversion is automatic its easy to forget its there most of the time :-). Do consider a `latin1` as the character set for it however for space conservation and speed of comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend getting rid of Partitioning and replacing

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`provincia`),
KEY `tel_fijo_idx` (`provincia`,`telefono_fijo`) USING BTREE,
KEY `tel_movil_idx` (`provincia`,`telefono_movil`) USING BTREE
```

with

```
PRIMARY KEY (`provincia`, id),
INDEX(id)
KEY `tel_fijo_idx` (`telefono_fijo`) USING BTREE,
KEY `tel_movil_idx` (`telefono_movil`) USING BTREE
```

The new PK is in the order that is usually needed for fetching.  Tacking on `id` makes the PK unique (a requirement for the PK).  This also makes the other two indexes unnecessary (at least for

The index on `id` (or at least starting with `id`) keeps `AUTO_INCREMENT` happy.

The other two indexes are similar to yours, and as fast even without Partitioning.

See "B+Tree" in Wikipedia.

Comparing a `VARCHAR` to an unquoted numeric string prevents index usage.  (Other combos work fine.)  This explains one of your questions -- `telefono_fijo = 3424527000`.

Back to your question:

With partitioning, here is an overview of how your SELECTs work:

1. Do "partition pruning" if possible.  It was possible in your two examples (`"partitions": ["p20"]`) shows that only one partition was to be used.
2. Use the `INDEX` (or `PRIMARY KEY`) to locate the row(s) desired.  Note:  The index is specific to the one partition.
3. If more than one partition was used (not in your case), combine the results from each partition.
4. Apply `GROUP`, `ORDER`, `LIMIT` (not in your case).

Without partitioning, but with my indexes:

1. Use a secondary index based on the phone number.  Note: In InnoDB, the PK is implicitly tacked onto the index, so `id` is also available for filtering.
2. That index row(s) will point to the row(s) in the data's BTree.
3. Apply `GROUP`, `ORDER`, `LIMIT` (not in your case).  Note that if you Grouped or ordered by the number, note that this extra step may not be needed.